# ssh - connection closed without any further information

Tags: ssh, 19.04, openssh

I'm currently having trouble with SSH configuration. It was working since about half a year and since this morning, it doesn't seems to work anymore.

I've tried a lot of things such as allow from all, regen the keys (don't really understand much about this tho).

I searched in auth.log but nothing is showing when I try to log in with a correct user.

Any idea ?

Here's the log I'm receiving from the ssh-v

```
ssh -v ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xxx
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for xx.xxx.xx.xxx
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xxx [xx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to xx.xxx.xx.xxx:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:xxxxxxxxx
debug1: Host '51.195.47.157' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Amael/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Connection closed by xx.xxx.xx.xxx port 22
```

Comment: `key_load_public` does not appear to be finding a key, of any type

Comment: Yeah but it is only a debug not an actual error.. It is supposed to work even with debug things, isn't it ? (I found that on others topics).